# Opportunities with read only access giving access for edit also

Tags: apex, community, sharing

While sharing opportunity with Read Only access to users using sharing rule, users are getting edit access as well. OWD for Account is public read only and Opportunity OWD is private.

Comment: Does user has Modify All permission on Profile level ? Please check the setting for Modify All Data on a profile level.

Comment: No at profile level only read create and edit permissions are given.

Comment: As any permission sets assigned ?

Comment: Users can able to edit their own Opportunity records. Is there any permission set assigned to users ?

Comment: No permission set is assigned and this behavior is same for all users that is users to whom read only permission is assigned are able to edit it as well.

Comment: If custom vf page for edit is replaced with standard edit functionality it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment

> If custom vf page for edit is replaced with standard edit
>   functionality it is working as expected.

It sounds like you are having issues where the VF Edit page is not honoring the OWD model defined in the Sharing Settings

A possible/probable cause is the presence of `without sharing` on the class  definition referencing the Opportunity object - most likely the VF Controller. [From the Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm?search_text=sharing):

> The with sharing keyword allows you to specify that the sharing rules
>   for the current user be taken into account for a class. You have to
>   explicitly set this keyword for the class because Apex code runs in
>   system context. In system context, Apex code has access to all objects
>   and fields— object permissions, field-level security, sharing rules
>   aren’t applied for the current user.

Some worthwhile reading can also be found in [Visualforce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) page 51 that discusses how you can have selective sharing control within a class wherein some methods enforce sharing and others don't (using inner classes)

Comment: Thanks...! this helps. Replacing without sharing by 'With sharing' worked.